# Building IO2D fails

Tags: c++, svg, openstreetmap

I'm building IO2D library (https://github.com/cpp-io2d/P0267_RefImpl) .

I followed this tutorial (https://github.com/cpp-io2d/P0267_RefImpl/blob/master/BUILDING.md) from the official documentation to build the library.

Building steps:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential
sudo apt install cmake
sudo apt install libcairo2-dev
sudo apt install libgraphicsmagick1-dev
sudo apt install libpng-dev
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/cpp-io2d/P0267_RefImpl
cd P0267_RefImpl
mkdir Debug
cd Debug
cmake --config Debug "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" ..
cmake --build .
```

But I always get a huge error.

Here's my environment and the required packages:

```bash
$ cmake --version 
cmake version 3.16.3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
$ dpkg -l | grep libcairo
ii  libcairo-gobject-perl                         1.005-2                               amd64        integrate Cairo into the Glib type system in Perl
ii  libcairo-gobject2:amd64                       1.16.0-4ubuntu1                       amd64        Cairo 2D vector graphics library (GObject library)
ii  libcairo-perl                                 1.107-1                               amd64        Perl interface to the Cairo graphics library
ii  libcairo-script-interpreter2:amd64            1.16.0-4ubuntu1                       amd64        Cairo 2D vector graphics library (script interpreter)
ii  libcairo2:amd64                               1.16.0-4ubuntu1                       amd64        Cairo 2D vector graphics library
ii  libcairo2-dev:amd64                           1.16.0-4ubuntu1                       amd64        Development files for the Cairo 2D graphics library
ii  libcairomm-1.0-1v5:amd64                      1.12.2-4build1                        amd64        C++ wrappers for Cairo (shared libraries)
$ dpkg -l | grep libgraphicsmagick
ii  libgraphicsmagick-q16-3                       1.4+really1.3.35-1                    amd64        format-independent image processing - C shared library
ii  libgraphicsmagick1-dev                        1.4+really1.3.35-1                    amd64        format-independent image processing - C development files
$ dpkg -l | grep libpng
ii  libpng-dev:amd64                              1.6.37-2                              amd64        PNG library - development (version 1.6)
ii  libpng-tools                                  1.6.37-2                              amd64        PNG library - tools (version 1.6)
ii  libpng16-16:amd64                             1.6.37-2                              amd64        PNG library - runtime (version 1.6)
$ make --version 
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

And here are the first few lines from the error I got (this is just a small part of it, but I can't put it all here because it's exceeding the character limit):

```bash
$ ls
 appveyor.yml   BUILDING.md   cmake   CMakeLists.txt   CONSUMING.md   Debug  'Design questions.md'   LICENSE.md   P0267_RefImpl   README.md   TODO.md
$ cd Debug/
$ cmake --config Debug "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
Default IO2D backend was not specified, choosing automatically...
Found Linux, using CAIRO_XLIB.
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Found Cairo: /usr/include/cairo (found version "1.16.0") 
-- Checking for module 'GraphicsMagick'
--   Found GraphicsMagick, version 1.3.35
-- Found GraphicsMagick: /usr/include/GraphicsMagick  
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/eslam/CppND/Course 1, Foundations/P0267_RefImpl/Debug
$ cmake --build .
Scanning dependencies of target io2d_core
[  1%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/P0267_RefImpl/CMakeFiles/io2d_core.dir/rgba_color.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/P0267_RefImpl/CMakeFiles/io2d_core.dir/xinterchangebuffer.cpp.o
[  5%] Linking CXX static library libio2d_core.a
[  5%] Built target io2d_core
Scanning dependencies of target io2d_cairo
[  7%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/P0267_RefImpl/cairo/CMakeFiles/io2d_cairo.dir/cairo_renderer-graphicsmagickinit.cpp.o
[  9%] Linking CXX static library libio2d_cairo.a
[  9%] Built target io2d_cairo
Scanning dependencies of target io2d_cairo_xlib
[ 11%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/P0267_RefImpl/cairo/xlib/CMakeFiles/io2d_cairo_xlib.dir/cairo_renderer_xlib.cpp.o
[ 12%] Linking CXX static library libio2d_cairo_xlib.a
[ 12%] Built target io2d_cairo_xlib
Scanning dependencies of target color_fill
[ 14%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/Samples/color_fill/CMakeFiles/color_fill.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 16%] Linking CXX executable color_fill
[ 16%] Built target color_fill
Scanning dependencies of target cpu_load
[ 18%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/Samples/cpu_load/CMakeFiles/cpu_load.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/Samples/cpu_load/CMakeFiles/cpu_load.dir/data_source.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/Samples/cpu_load/CMakeFiles/cpu_load.dir/profiler_linux.cpp.o
[ 24%] Linking CXX executable cpu_load
[ 24%] Built target cpu_load
Scanning dependencies of target draw_cpp
[ 25%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/Samples/draw_cpp/CMakeFiles/draw_cpp.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 27%] Linking CXX executable draw_cpp
[ 27%] Built target draw_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target life
[ 29%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/Samples/life/CMakeFiles/life.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 31%] Linking CXX executable life
[ 31%] Built target life
Scanning dependencies of target pugixml
[ 33%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/Samples/maps/external/pugixml/CMakeFiles/pugixml.dir/src/pugixml.cpp.o
[ 35%] Linking CXX static library libpugixml.a
[ 35%] Built target pugixml
Scanning dependencies of target maps
[ 37%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/Samples/maps/CMakeFiles/maps.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/Samples/maps/CMakeFiles/maps.dir/model.cpp.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/Samples/maps/CMakeFiles/maps.dir/render.cpp.o
[ 42%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/Samples/maps/CMakeFiles/maps.dir/http.cpp.o
[ 44%] Linking CXX executable maps
[ 44%] Built target maps
Scanning dependencies of target rocks_in_space
[ 46%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/Samples/rocks_in_space/CMakeFiles/rocks_in_space.dir/Asteroid.cpp.o
[ 48%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/Samples/rocks_in_space/CMakeFiles/rocks_in_space.dir/Game.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/Samples/rocks_in_space/CMakeFiles/rocks_in_space.dir/Input.cpp.o
[ 51%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/Samples/rocks_in_space/CMakeFiles/rocks_in_space.dir/Maths.cpp.o
[ 53%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/Samples/rocks_in_space/CMakeFiles/rocks_in_space.dir/Physics.cpp.o
[ 55%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/Samples/rocks_in_space/CMakeFiles/rocks_in_space.dir/Ship.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/Samples/rocks_in_space/CMakeFiles/rocks_in_space.dir/LinuxMain.cpp.o
[ 59%] Linking CXX executable rocks_in_space
[ 59%] Built target rocks_in_space
Scanning dependencies of target sprites
[ 61%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/Samples/sprites/CMakeFiles/sprites.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 62%] Linking CXX executable sprites
[ 62%] Built target sprites
Scanning dependencies of target svg
[ 64%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/Samples/svg/CMakeFiles/svg.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object P0267_RefImpl/Samples/svg/CMakeFiles/svg.dir/svg.cpp.o
In file included from /home/eslam/CppND/Course 1, Foundations/P0267_RefImpl/P0267_RefImpl/Samples/svg/external/svgpp/include/svgpp/document_traversal.hpp:11,
                 from /home/eslam/CppND/Course 1, Foundations/P0267_RefImpl/P0267_RefImpl/Samples/svg/external/svgpp/include/svgpp/svgpp.hpp:1,
                 from /home/eslam/CppND/Course 1, Foundations/P0267_RefImpl/P0267_RefImpl/Samples/svg/svg.cpp:5:
/home/eslam/CppND/Course 1, Foundations/P0267_RefImpl/P0267_RefImpl/Samples/svg/external/svgpp/include/svgpp/attribute_dispatcher.hpp: In instantiation of ‘bool svgpp::detail::viewport_attribute_dispatcher<ElementTag, Context, Args>::on_exit_attributes() [with ElementTag = svgpp::tag::element::svg; Context = Canvas; Args = {svgpp::referencing_element<void>, svgpp::processed_elements<boost::mpl::set12<svgpp::tag::element::svg, svgpp::tag::element::g, svgpp::tag::element::use_, svgpp::tag::element::circle, svgpp::tag::element::ellipse, svgpp::tag::element::line, svgpp::tag::element::path, svgpp::tag::element::polygon, svgpp::tag::element::polyline, svgpp::tag::element::rect, svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::element::stop> >, svgpp::processed_attributes<boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::x, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::y, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::width, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::height, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::viewBox, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::preserveAspectRatio, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::path, svgpp::tag::attribute::d>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::rect, svgpp::tag::attribute::x>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::rect, svgpp::tag::attribute::y>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::rect, svgpp::tag::attribute::width>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::rect, svgpp::tag::attribute::height>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::rect, svgpp::tag::attribute::rx>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::rect, svgpp::tag::attribute::ry>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::circle, svgpp::tag::attribute::cx>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::circle, svgpp::tag::attribute::cy>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::circle, svgpp::tag::attribute::r>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::ellipse, svgpp::tag::attribute::cx>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::ellipse, svgpp::tag::attribute::cy>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::ellipse, svgpp::tag::attribute::rx>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::ellipse, svgpp::tag::attribute::ry>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::line, svgpp::tag::attribute::x1>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::line, svgpp::tag::attribute::y1>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::line, svgpp::tag::attribute::x2>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::line, svgpp::tag::attribute::y2>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::polyline, svgpp::tag::attribute::points>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::polygon, svgpp::tag::attribute::points>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::use_, svgpp::tag::attribute::xlink::href>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::stop, svgpp::tag::attribute::stop_opacity>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::stop, svgpp::tag::attribute::stop_color>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::stop, svgpp::tag::attribute::offset>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::attribute::id>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::attribute::y2>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::attribute::x2>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::attribute::y1>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::attribute::x1>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::attribute::gradientTransform>, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::stroke_opacity, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::fill_opacity, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::opacity, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::fill, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::stroke_width, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::stroke, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::transform, boost::mpl::set0<mpl_::na> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > >, svgpp::viewport_policy<svgpp::policy::viewport::as_transform>, svgpp::path_policy<PathPolicy>, svgpp::context_factories<ChildContextFactories>, svgpp::color_factory<svgpp::factory::color::percentage_adapter<ColorFactoryBase> >, svgpp::length_policy<svgpp::policy::length::forward_to_method<Canvas, const svgpp::factory::length::unitless<float, float, svgpp::tag::length_units::mm> > >, svgpp::attribute_traversal_policy<AttributeTraversal>}]’:
/home/eslam/CppND/Course 1, Foundations/P0267_RefImpl/P0267_RefImpl/Samples/svg/external/svgpp/include/svgpp/document_traversal.hpp:174:52:   required from ‘static bool svgpp::document_traversal<Args>::load_attributes(const XMLElement&, Context&, ElementTag) [with ReferencingElement = void; XMLElement = const rapidxml_ns::xml_node<>*; Context = Canvas; ElementTag = svgpp::tag::element::svg; Args = {svgpp::processed_elements<boost::mpl::set12<svgpp::tag::element::svg, svgpp::tag::element::g, svgpp::tag::element::use_, svgpp::tag::element::circle, svgpp::tag::element::ellipse, svgpp::tag::element::line, svgpp::tag::element::path, svgpp::tag::element::polygon, svgpp::tag::element::polyline, svgpp::tag::element::rect, svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::element::stop> >, svgpp::processed_attributes<boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::x, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::y, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::width, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::height, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::viewBox, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::preserveAspectRatio, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::path, svgpp::tag::attribute::d>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::rect, svgpp::tag::attribute::x>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::rect, svgpp::tag::attribute::y>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::rect, svgpp::tag::attribute::width>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::rect, svgpp::tag::attribute::height>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::rect, svgpp::tag::attribute::rx>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::rect, svgpp::tag::attribute::ry>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::circle, svgpp::tag::attribute::cx>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::circle, svgpp::tag::attribute::cy>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::circle, svgpp::tag::attribute::r>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::ellipse, svgpp::tag::attribute::cx>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::ellipse, svgpp::tag::attribute::cy>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::ellipse, svgpp::tag::attribute::rx>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::ellipse, svgpp::tag::attribute::ry>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::line, svgpp::tag::attribute::x1>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::line, svgpp::tag::attribute::y1>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::line, svgpp::tag::attribute::x2>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::line, svgpp::tag::attribute::y2>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::polyline, svgpp::tag::attribute::points>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::polygon, svgpp::tag::attribute::points>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::use_, svgpp::tag::attribute::xlink::href>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::stop, svgpp::tag::attribute::stop_opacity>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::stop, svgpp::tag::attribute::stop_color>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::stop, svgpp::tag::attribute::offset>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::attribute::id>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::attribute::y2>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::attribute::x2>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::attribute::y1>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::attribute::x1>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::attribute::gradientTransform>, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::stroke_opacity, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::fill_opacity, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::opacity, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::fill, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::stroke_width, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::stroke, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::transform, boost::mpl::set0<mpl_::na> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > >, svgpp::viewport_policy<svgpp::policy::viewport::as_transform>, svgpp::path_policy<PathPolicy>, svgpp::context_factories<ChildContextFactories>, svgpp::color_factory<svgpp::factory::color::percentage_adapter<ColorFactoryBase> >, svgpp::length_policy<svgpp::policy::length::forward_to_method<Canvas, const svgpp::factory::length::unitless<float, float, svgpp::tag::length_units::mm> > >, svgpp::attribute_traversal_policy<AttributeTraversal>}]’
/home/eslam/CppND/Course 1, Foundations/P0267_RefImpl/P0267_RefImpl/Samples/svg/external/svgpp/include/svgpp/document_traversal.hpp:138:49:   required from ‘static bool svgpp::document_traversal<Args>::load_element(const XMLElement&, Context&, ElementTag) [with ExpectedChildElements = boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::radialGradient, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::defs, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::g, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::svg, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::symbol, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::use_, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::circle, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::ellipse, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::line, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::path, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::polygon, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::polyline, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::rect, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::desc, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::metadata, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::title, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::animate, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::animateColor, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::animateMotion, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::animateTransform, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::set, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::view, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::text, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::switch_, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::style, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::script, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::pattern, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::mask, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::marker, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::image, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::foreignObject, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::font_face, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::font, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::filter, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::cursor, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::color_profile, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::clipPath, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::altGlyphDef, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::element::a, boost::mpl::set0<> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > >; ReferencingElement = void; XMLElement = const rapidxml_ns::xml_node<>*; Context = Canvas; ElementTag = svgpp::tag::element::svg; Args = {svgpp::processed_elements<boost::mpl::set12<svgpp::tag::element::svg, svgpp::tag::element::g, svgpp::tag::element::use_, svgpp::tag::element::circle, svgpp::tag::element::ellipse, svgpp::tag::element::line, svgpp::tag::element::path, svgpp::tag::element::polygon, svgpp::tag::element::polyline, svgpp::tag::element::rect, svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::element::stop> >, svgpp::processed_attributes<boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::x, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::y, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::width, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::height, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::viewBox, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::preserveAspectRatio, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::path, svgpp::tag::attribute::d>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::rect, svgpp::tag::attribute::x>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::rect, svgpp::tag::attribute::y>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::rect, svgpp::tag::attribute::width>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::rect, svgpp::tag::attribute::height>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::rect, svgpp::tag::attribute::rx>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::rect, svgpp::tag::attribute::ry>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::circle, svgpp::tag::attribute::cx>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::circle, svgpp::tag::attribute::cy>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::circle, svgpp::tag::attribute::r>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::ellipse, svgpp::tag::attribute::cx>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::ellipse, svgpp::tag::attribute::cy>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::ellipse, svgpp::tag::attribute::rx>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::ellipse, svgpp::tag::attribute::ry>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::line, svgpp::tag::attribute::x1>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::line, svgpp::tag::attribute::y1>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::line, svgpp::tag::attribute::x2>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::line, svgpp::tag::attribute::y2>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::polyline, svgpp::tag::attribute::points>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::polygon, svgpp::tag::attribute::points>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::use_, svgpp::tag::attribute::xlink::href>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::stop, svgpp::tag::attribute::stop_opacity>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::stop, svgpp::tag::attribute::stop_color>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::stop, svgpp::tag::attribute::offset>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::attribute::id>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::attribute::y2>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::attribute::x2>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::attribute::y1>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::attribute::x1>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::attribute::gradientTransform>, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::stroke_opacity, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::fill_opacity, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::opacity, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::fill, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::stroke_width, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::stroke, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::transform, boost::mpl::set0<mpl_::na> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > >, svgpp::viewport_policy<svgpp::policy::viewport::as_transform>, svgpp::path_policy<PathPolicy>, svgpp::context_factories<ChildContextFactories>, svgpp::color_factory<svgpp::factory::color::percentage_adapter<ColorFactoryBase> >, svgpp::length_policy<svgpp::policy::length::forward_to_method<Canvas, const svgpp::factory::length::unitless<float, float, svgpp::tag::length_units::mm> > >, svgpp::attribute_traversal_policy<AttributeTraversal>}]’
/home/eslam/CppND/Course 1, Foundations/P0267_RefImpl/P0267_RefImpl/Samples/svg/external/svgpp/include/svgpp/document_traversal.hpp:118:12:   required from ‘static bool svgpp::document_traversal<Args>::load_expected_element(const XMLElement&, Context&, ElementTag) [with XMLElement = const rapidxml_ns::xml_node<>*; Context = Canvas; ElementTag = svgpp::tag::element::svg; Args = {svgpp::processed_elements<boost::mpl::set12<svgpp:...
boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::line, svgpp::tag::attribute::x2>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::line, svgpp::tag::attribute::y2>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::polyline, svgpp::tag::attribute::points>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::polygon, svgpp::tag::attribute::points>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::use_, svgpp::tag::attribute::xlink::href>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::stop, svgpp::tag::attribute::stop_opacity>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::stop, svgpp::tag::attribute::stop_color>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::stop, svgpp::tag::attribute::offset>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::attribute::id>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::attribute::y2>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::attribute::x2>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::attribute::y1>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::attribute::x1>, boost::mpl::s_item<boost::mpl::pair<svgpp::tag::element::linearGradient, svgpp::tag::attribute::gradientTransform>, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::stroke_opacity, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::fill_opacity, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::opacity, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::fill, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::stroke_width, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::stroke, boost::mpl::s_item<svgpp::tag::attribute::transform, boost::mpl::set0<mpl_::na> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > >, svgpp::viewport_policy<svgpp::policy::viewport::as_transform>, svgpp::path_policy<PathPolicy>, svgpp::context_factories<ChildContextFactories>, svgpp::color_factory<svgpp::factory::color::percentage_adapter<ColorFactoryBase> >, svgpp::length_policy<svgpp::policy::length::forward_to_method<Canvas, const svgpp::factory::length::unitless<float, float, svgpp::tag::length_units::mm> > >, svgpp::attribute_traversal_policy<AttributeTraversal> >&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
  205 | class on_exit_attributes_functor: boost::noncopyable
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
. . .
. . . 
. . .
```

My environment is Linux Mint Una 20.3, `cmake` version is 3.16.3 and `make` is 4.2.1

But the building fails in the last step

```
cmake --build .
```

If it helps, the error happens while linking `svg.cpp.o` and `main.cpp.o`

I checked the github issues page and they don't seem to be responsive and no one had this issue

Comment: No external links please! Questions need to be self contained here, more specifically a [mcve].

Comment: Don't link to important information that the question cannot be understood without. The links will eventually fail and the question will become not useful, and that's assuming they are not immediately blocked by some user's firewalls.

Comment: Have you checked [the issue tracker](https://github.com/cpp-io2d/P0267_RefImpl/issues) to see if others have reported this problem to the maintainers? Could be a viable work-around already established.

Comment: Are you building it out of interest, or for practical use?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have edited the question and removed Pastebin links, and added steps to reproduce the problem

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sorry what do you mean by out of interest? I'm enrolled in Udacity's C++ Nanodegree program and I need to build it to proceed with my first project. I have posted my question here as the Udacity staff didn't help the least.

Comment: I mean can you use some other library that's not unmaintained?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I can't because this is the library used in the course and some parts of the code depend on it

Comment: Go to your teacher. If they insist on using an obscure library, they should provide build instructions. Also I would push for the course being changed for a different library.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I second that. I will contact the staff about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using a docker image based on Ubuntu 18.04 and it's working perfectly

Comment: Could you please clarify how you managed to solve this issue. I am trying to do on Ubuntu and I am not getting anywhere